# how to call rest api inside aws lambda function using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i have created aws lambda function. i want to use rest api calls inside my lambda function.
Is there any reference how to connect it to rest api using nodejs

Comment: You just forget `lambda function` and call rest api using nodejs.

Comment: i am new to nodejs, is there any samples available for calling rest api using ngrok

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? If yes please update it as your answer. I am also trying to implement the same.

Answer (score 10):

```js
const https = require('https')

// data for the body you want to send.
const data = JSON.stringify({
  todo: 'Cook dinner.'
});

const options = {
  hostname: 'yourapihost.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  },
};

const response = await doRequest(options, data);
console.log("response", JSON.stringify(response));

/**
 * Do a request with options provided.
 *
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {Object} data
 * @return {Promise} a promise of request
 */
function doRequest(options, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding("utf8");
      let responseBody = "";

      res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        responseBody += chunk;
      });

      res.on("end", () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(responseBody));
      });
    });

    req.on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call rest api inside lambda function, you can use request package:

install request package via npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Then inside lambda function try this to call rest api:

```
    var req = require('request');
    const params = {
        url: 'API_REST_URL',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        json: JSON.parse({ id: 1})
    };
    req.post(params, function(err, res, body) {
        if(err){
            console.log('------error------', err);
        } else{
            console.log('------success--------', body);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this in lambda but doesn't work for me. where as same rest api work in postman and python script also.

Comment: Using this how we can pass the body data of the POST API? Also how we can parse the response of the service?

Answer (score 1):

```
const superagent = require('superagent');

exports.handler =  async(event) => {
    return await startPoint();  // use promise function for api 
}


function startPoint(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    superagent
    .get(apiEndPoint)
    .end((err, res) => {
        ...



       });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda now supports `Node.js 18` ,which has support for global `fetch` , you can now easily call the REST api endpoints like this

```
// index.mjs 

export const handler = async(event) => {
    
    const res = await fetch('https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.json');
    if (res.ok) {
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are asking about creating a HTTP rest endpoint in lambda using
   nodejs. Here is the example. 
   https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-simple-http-endpoint

If you are asking about access an external API inside lambda using
   nodejs. Here is an example.

https://github.com/robm26/SkillsDataAccess/blob/master/src/CallService/index.js

Hope this helps.